# Button to hide/fold code in revealjs Quarto

Tags: quarto, reveal.js, code-folding

I would like to use a [`code-fold`](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html) option in a revealjs Quarto presentation, or something similar. When we use this option in a code chunk like this:

````
---
title: "Code-fold in revealjs"
format: revealjs
code-fold: true
---

## Graph

```{r}
#| code-fold: true
#| code-summary: "expand for full code"
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
                  xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3),
                  yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  geom_smooth() 
```
````

Output:

[image]

We can see there is no code-fold button. So I was wondering if anyone knows if there is an option like that in `revealjs`?

Comment: But would not it be messier when you do `code-unfold` in case of presentation? It will be highly likely that the figure will go out of the presentation margin. Right?

Comment: Hi @shafee, that is true, but I would like to add if possible a scrollable slide. But I would like to have a button to make it possible to hide and show the code.

Comment: @shafee, Maybe you understand how this is done [here](https://meghan.rbind.io/blog/quarto-slides/#code-folding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

**Just use `echo: true`, No need to use that Lua filter.**

Quarto `revealjs` format by default uses `echo: false` for every chunk. That's code-folding will not work by default (because there is no code block to fold in the rendered slide).

````
---
title: "Code-fold in revealjs"
format: revealjs
---

## Graph

```{r}
#| echo: true
#| code-fold: true
#| code-summary: "expand for full code"
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
                  xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3),
                  yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  geom_smooth() 
```
````

---

[image: code folding in revealjs]

---

You can use the following Lua filter to add code folding

````
---
title: "Code-fold in revealjs"
format: revealjs
filters: 
  - code-fold.lua
---

## Graph

```{r}
#| echo: true
#| code-fold: true
#| code-summary: "expand for full code"
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
                  xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3),
                  yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  geom_smooth() 
```
````

**code-fold.lua**

```
local str = pandoc.utils.stringify

local template_fold_p1 = [[
<details>
  <summary>
  %s
  </summary>
]]

local template_fold_p2 = [[
%s
</details>
]]

function Div(el)
  if el.attributes['code-fold'] then
    local code_summary = str(el.attributes['code-summary'])
    local fold = string.format(template_fold_p1, code_summary)
    local fold_rb1 = pandoc.RawBlock('html', fold)
    local fold_rb2 = pandoc.RawBlock('html', template_fold_p2)
    el.content:insert(1, fold_rb1)
    el.content:insert(fold_rb1)
    return el
  end
end
```

Comment: That was simple! Maybe it should be better mentioned in the documentation? Thanks again @shafee